# Django - Overriding cleaned_data

Tags: django, overriding

I have a form with fields that are not on the correspondent model. I use these "virtual" fields to fill a real one with the clean() method.

So, the user enters with data in the "virtual" field and I have to fill the real field with this same data.

I thought that overriding the cleaned_data["real_field"] would be possible, but I cannot do it.

My code is something like this:

```
(...)
cleaned_data['real_field'] = cleaned_data['virtual_field']
(...)
return cleaned_data
```

Any ideas on another way I can do it, or if I am doing it wrong, how do I fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nevermind, I had an error. The real field was not declared in the fieldsets (admin.py).

Answer (score 8):

In your form class:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    cleaned_data['real_field'] = cleaned_data['virtual_field']
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: can it be done in a `clean_field(self)` method also?

Comment: by the time `clean_<fieldname>` is called I would not assume the other field is cleaned already... If your you need more than one field in order to validate/normalize the data, the recommended place to do it is the `form.clean` method.